# what is the difference between / and //?

Tags: directory, ftp

I have been facing this wierd problem while trying to montor an FTP server. 
If I try to use `ftp://192.x.x.x/home/$USER/output` , the monitoring tool fails to pickup the folder.
However, if I use `ftp://192.x.x.x//home/$USER/output`, then the FTP folder is picked up easily.
So I want to know, what is the difference between  / and  // ?

Comment: Makes one wonder what software is involved. What do you use to monitor and ftp-server is installed?

Comment: Monitoring tool is FuseHQ

Comment: I couldn't find anything special for your case in the [RFC](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#page-22). As far as I understand, this is for the root-hierarchy from within an absolute path. You should be able to add as many slashes there to any URL and always get the same response.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this helps.

A path name consisting of a single slash `/` resolves to root directory of the process.  A path name that begins with two slashes `//` may be interpreted diffrently, although more than two leading slashes shall be treated as a single slash.

Most implementations simply treat // as / , but may still show // .

Also see [UNIX, difference between path starting with '/' and '//'](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12283/unix-difference-between-path-starting-with-and#12291)